# Responsive Design: Elements with fixed size & fixed position relative to each other. Text wrapped alongside

Tags: html, css

The below snippet shows a section of my page design. The requirements are:

1. `img` and `canvas` elements with sizes that are always in proportion and
   with positions relative to each other that do not change. They need
   to appear attached to each other.
2. On a regular size laptop/desktop screen, the `img` should be approx' 300px wide and the text should show along side it. Not below.
3. On smaller screens, the text can either drop below or the image can shrink.
4. The container elements (`T2` and `C2`) need to actually contain the elements within it. For example, if I use the `float` attribute, the bottom of my `p`, `canvas` and `img` elements is below the bottom of the `C2` element. It doesn't work.
5. The amount of text in the `p` element is subject to change. As such, the height of the container elements (`T2` and `C2`) needs to be flexible without the need for re-coding.

I've tried two approaches:

1. Absolute positioning for everything and a very complex script which re-sizes and moves things depending on window size or changes to window size.
2. The below. Relative positioning of container elements to enable absolute positioning of `img` and `canvas` elements within it. Default positioning for `p` text with margins to accommodate `img` and `canvas`. `Min-height` for `p` text to stop container height going below `img` + `canvas` height.

My objective is simplicity and best practice without the use of a plugin/library or 3rd party code. *Does the below look like I've achieved this? If not, suggestions please?* (perhaps some javascript for fine-tuning)

*If I was to consider a free and publicly available CSS or javascript library or plugin, what are the best available these days?* Looks like bootstrap grid system will be my first port of call.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "10px Arial";
ctx.fillText("Canvas with fixed height and width. Absolute positioning.",10,50);
```

```css
.chapter {
      width: 90%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-width: 1000px;
      border: 1px solid red;
      position:relative;
    }
    
#img1 {
      border: 1px solid green;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0px;
      top:80px;
      height: 200px;
      width: 200px;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      z-index:10;
    }
    
#canvas {
      border: 1px solid blue;
      position: absolute;
      right: 125px;
      top:30px;
      height: 150px;
      width: 150px;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      z-index:9;
    }
    
#text {
      border:1px solid purple;
      width:50%;
      max-width:500px;
      min-height:400px;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div class="template" id="T2">
<div class="chapter" id="C2">
      <p>Parent element with relative positioning. Needs to contain text box, canvas and image.</p>
      <img src="" id="img1" alt="Image with fixed height and width. Absolute positioning." />
      <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>  
      <div id="text"><p>Text box with minimum height greater than img + canvas height.</p>
      </div>   
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `display:flex` on the container to control each of two sub-containers `imgCanvasContainer` and `text`. When the screen is small, text will fall below. Further control of element dimensions can be achieved using @media query as in:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    #text {
        width:100% !important;
    }
}
```

Here's a snippet:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.font = "10px Arial";
ctx.fillText("Canvas with fixed height and width. Absolute positioning.",10,50);
```

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    #text {
        width:100% !important;
    }
}

.chapter {
      width: 90%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      max-width: 1000px;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
    
#img1 {
      border: 1px solid green;
      position: absolute;
      right: 0px;
      top:80px;
      height: 200px;
      width: 200px;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      z-index:10;
    }
    
#canvas {
      border: 1px solid blue;
      position: absolute;
      right: 125px;
      top:30px;
      height: 150px;
      width: 150px;
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      z-index:9;
    }
    
.imgCanvasContainer {
  position:relative;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  align-self: start;
}   

.flexContainer {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap-reverse;
}
    
#text {
      border:1px solid purple;
      width:50%;
      max-width:500px;
      min-height:400px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="template" id="T2">
<div class="chapter" id="C2">
      <p>Parent element with relative positioning. Needs to contain text box, canvas and image.</p>
      <div class="flexContainer">
        <div id="text"><p>Text box with minimum height greater than img + canvas height.</p>
        </div>   
        <div class="imgCanvasContainer">
          <img src="" id="img1" alt="Image with fixed height and width. Absolute positioning." />
          <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>  
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
</div>
```